# Failure on apt-get

Tags: raspbian-jessie, web-server, apt

I have a remote site where I have a brand new raspberry pi that I would like to setup as a web server. I want to use nginx, and so I ran `sudo apt-get install nginx`. This should be something incredibly simple, but for some reason, it didn't work. I got the following error message:

```
E: The value 'jessie' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

I have never seen an error message like this (and I've worked with quite a few pi's) and I can't do anything right now, nothing that I run with `apt-get` will work. What could be wrong?

In addition, when I try to run `sudo apt update` it gets a little of the way through and then I get the following error messages for about 25 or 30 files:

```
Target package is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch.list:1
```

Comment: Have you tried using Raspbian Stretch on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @RPImaniac I have not, do you think that would fix the problem?

Comment: to rule out the obvious did you do an apt update first?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I did, and it gets a little of the way through and then says `Target package [there are about 25 listed] is configured multiple times at /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch.list:1`

Comment: Those details belong in your question, not the comments. I would look at sources list and remove the duplicates (leaving the source that matches your current version).

Comment: @Adam McGurk you could always try flashing your sd card with the latest Raspbian Stretch OS and see if that fixes it....